# How to parse a message to only extract the body, every time?

Tags: php, email, email-parsing

I'm coding an email piping and I'm getting the message and everything but I'm struggling when it comes to extracting the new user reply and add it to the ticket log.

Some email clients add something like "On 2011-03-14, at 6:00 AM, Stack Overflow wrote:" before older messages other don't... I'm completely lost.

Please help.

Comment: Ugh, I think this is fairly complex. Are you parsing text only, or HTML mails as well?

Comment: Yeah, there is no standard way to do this.  Gmail does it by comparing the reply to the original, and figuring out what has changed.  As Pekka has pointed out, you have issues with HTML vs. Plain Text as well.  Most e-mail clients send a plain-text version alongside an HTML version, but not all.  If the plant-text version exists, you might prefer to process that one, unless the formatting is important to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text "on xxx, foo wrote" is part of the email text because the author's included that automatically and the author did not delete it. So you apparently did everything right :)